# Diferenciar produto de ingrediente

Tags: c#, modelagem

Estou tentando fazer um sistema para venda de Açaí. Em um açaí pode se adicionar muitos ingredientes como paçoca, leite em pó, frutas e etc... O açaí também pode ser vendido em potes de 250ml, 500ml e 750ml. Dependendo de em qual pote for vendido, uma quantidade N vai ser removida do estoque. O mesmo se aplica aos ingredientes adicionadas. Vale lembrar que o estabelecimento também vende garrafa de água, sucos, refrigerantes, que não deixam de ser produtos!

Enfim, estou tentando fazer o modelo, e até então me encontro assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu defini que um **Ingrediente** e um **Produto** são um tipo de **Item**, pois possuem estoque, tem um preço (que em caso do ingrediente vai adicionar ao preço final do produto), portanto eles herdam da classe abstrata **Item**. A classe **Ingrediente** possui uma lista das categorias que ela pode ser adicionada, por exemplo: **Leite em pó** pode ser adicionado na categoria **Açaí**, mas nunca na categoria **Refrigerante**.

Quero saber se o modelo está bom, pensei na possibilidade de usar o padrão decorator, mas não sei se terei problemas ao inserir no banco de dados. Utilizarei C# e Fluent Nhibernate com MySQL. Enfim, como resolver o problema do Pote de 250ml/750ml? E o fato de nem todos os ingredientes serem compatíveis com todos os produtos, fiz uma boa abordagem do problema?

Aceito sugestões sobre qualquer parte do modelo para tentar resolver problema, desde que não haja gambiarras para gravar no banco de dados(que também está sujeito a mudanças).

**EDIT**
Seguindo conselho, alterei o diagrama e este encontra-se assim agora:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Resolvido o problema de um produto pode vir a gastar X insumos.
Porém me encontro agora na seguinte situação. Se meu cliente compra uma garrafa de água de um fornecedor, ele vende a garrafa de água inteira sem gastar nenhum insumo, a garrafa é o próprio estoque, como resolver?
Pensei em criar uma classe estoque, mas como poderia ligar ao estoque Insumo e Produto ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Em que outra categoria `Leite em pó` pode ser adicionado além de `Açaí`? Algum ingrediente pode ser adicionado na categoria `Refrigerante`?

Comment: Me parece que você está tentando resolver com um único modelo uma quantidade imensa de problemas (estoque de insumos, controle de insumos utilizados na fabricação do produto, estoque de produtos, ...) e estes problemas parecem não estar ainda bem formulados - por enquanto existe só uma noção geral de todos os problemas. Minha sugestão: escolha o problema mais importante, defina-o bem, desenhe um modelo que o atenda, implemente, valide. Escolha o próximo problema, defina-o bem, refatore o modelo, implemente, valide. Repita o ciclo.

Comment: Eu acho importante separar o conceito de estoque do conceito de produto final vendido, pois na prática, são coisas diferentes mesmo. A Banana que você põe no açaí não é um ítem, e nem o açaí, pois você compra em um "formato" e vende fracionado. Assim como um ítem do estoque de uma loja de construção é o cimento, e você pode vender 1kg de cimento separadamente (fracionado). No estoque você tem sacos de cimento de 60Kg. Melhor não misturar conceitos forçadamente. O estoque tem quilos de banana, o açaí tem unidades. O estoque tem quantidades de açaí, que são fracionadas e viram produtos.

Comment: @Caffé Acredito que não, quis deixar livre pro usuário definir isso, pois caso ele queira por exemplo criar o produto vitamina e dizer que existem coisas que possam ser incrementadas, ele possa fazer isso.

Comment: @Bacco Por falta de conhecimento em planejamento não entendo bem o assunto, porém, isso não gera conteúdo duplicado? Em estoque tenho Açai 800ml, e em Item tenho Açai, também? Como o insumo se relaciona com o produto? O estoque é do insumo ou do produto? E quando o produto for inteiro?

Comment: @Lizard Vc tem produtos que se "relacionam" com o estoque. Você pode ter uma tabela de produtos com uma referencia assim: O produto açai 750ml "desconta" 0.75 L do estoque de açaí, se a entrada de estoque for em litros, por exemplo. O opcional Banana desconta 50g do Kg de banana, e assim vai.

Comment: @Bacco então eu vou ter que criar uma tabela de gastos? Meu cliente quando cadastrar um novo produto vai informar que o produto X gasta Y de tantos ingredientes?

Comment: @Lizard é o que eu normalmente faria neste caso, mas tem mais um monte de detalhes que um bom estoque tem que ter pra fechar redondinho (conciliação de perdas, etc). Cabe a você avaliar o que é melhor no caso real. São muitas possibilidades pra eu poder comentar aqui. Não tem uma regra universal, cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Vou seguir o conselho de vocês dois e remodelar. Depois edito com as alterações para (caso vocês queiram) avaliarem

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta com uma sugestão de modelo. Fique à vontade para questionar eu posso adicionar mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro partir de um problema bem elaborado, e desenhar o modelo para resolver este um problema, implementar o software, e daí seguir para o próximo problema, o que pode implicar numa refatoração do modelo e do software já desenvolvido até então. Esta abordagem pode ser chamada de **"Design Emergente"**, e está muito na moda :-)

Por exemplo:

> Problema: baixar estoque de insumos a partir da fabricação de um
>   produto.

Modelagem para resolver este problema:

- Insumo (ex: Leite em pó, paçoca, banana)
- Produto (ex: Açaí, Vitamina)
- Composição de produto (insumos utilizados na fabricação de um produto)
- Baixa de Insumo (oriunda da fabricação de um produto)

Quando um produto é fabricado, vários registros são adicionados à entidade *"Baixa de Insumo"*, e o estoque de insumos é atualizado (são deduzidas frações ou unidades das entidades *"Insumo"*).

Sugestão: deixe herança pro final. Não inicie uma modelagem já pensando em herança. Comece imaginando que você não pode contar com este recurso. O motivo é simples: herança adiciona complexidade e tentamos sempre manter o sistema o mais simples possível.

Comment: Quando o produto é por exemplo uma garrafa d'agua ele é produto, não tem composição, mas tem estoque. Como resolver essa situação?

Comment: atualizei a perguntei

Comment: @Lizard Você quer manter informação de estoque apenas dos produtos revendidos ou também dos de fabricação própria (ex: 10 açaís de paçoca no freezer)?

Comment: somente dos prontos (garrafa de água) e dos insumos

Comment: @Lizard Que tal renomear *Insumo* para *Produto* e *Produto* para *Produto Fabricado*?